# side menu closing when tap-ing on menu item

Tags: mobile, menu, tap, sidr

I am working on a website and i try to make the side menu (sidr) close when i access a menu item. Usually after i click/tap on one, the menu still stays and i need to close it using the menu button again.

I succeeded to make it work on desktops, but i dont know how to make it on mobile.

Could anyone help me?

Here is the code i used to make it work on desktop:

```
<script src="js/jquery.sidr.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#simple-menu').sidr();
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).click(function () {
$.sidr('close');
});

$(document).keyup(function ( e ) {
var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
if ( key === 27 ) {
$.sidr('close');
}
});

</script>
```

Waiting for your answer! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will help you

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('button_to_show_menu, .linksfromUL li a').click(function(){
    $('#hidden_menu').slideToggle(100);          
    });
    });

#button_to_show_menu - the button to show your menu
.linksfromUL li a - links inside ul li
#hidden_menu - the side menu
```

When you click the button to show your menu, the menu will apear and it will close after you click the button or the links inside ul.